# Parallelise a simulation using 'foreach' and 'doParallel'; "error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't'"

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I want to parallelise a simulation.

I used this example of a simple parallelization, which works just fine.

```
#install.packages("foreach")
#install.packages("doParallel")
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
# replication setup for parallelization


number_cores <- 4 # number of cores 


# parameters
iter <- 1:100

n_samp <- c(100,200)

design <- expand.grid(iter = iter, 
                      n_samp = n_samp
)

# dgp 
dgp <- function(n_samp){
  x <- rnorm(n_samp)
  y <- 2*x + rnorm(n_samp)
  dat <- data.frame(x,y)
  return(dat)
}

one_simulation <- function(n_samp){
  dat <- dgp(n_samp)
  mod <- lm(y~x, data = dat)
  return(coef(summary(mod))[1,1])
}

many_simulations <- function(design){
  res <- rep(NA, nrow(design))
  for(row in 1:nrow(design)){
    res[row] <- one_simulation(n_samp = design[row,])
  }
  return(res)
}


# parallelization using doParallel and foreach ----------------------------
# set up cluster
doParallel::registerDoParallel(number_cores)

# run simulation
start <- Sys.time() # for microbenchmarking
temp_result <- foreach (i = seq_len(number_cores)) %dopar% { # %dopar% evaluates in parallel
  many_simulations(design)
}
Sys.time()-start

# stop cluster
doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()

res <- do.call(rbind, temp_result)
save(res, file = "sim_res_gamma_test.rda")
```

Now I wanted to use this approach for a more complicated simulation. (I cant share the whole code, since its a lot). I can run the complicated simulation and it works fine, it just takes a lot of time to run. When I try the parallelization for the more complicated simulation, which has the same structure, I'm using this code:
It's the exact same approach, I'm only committing an other main-function to the parallelization.

```
# parallelization using doParallel and foreach ----------------------------
# set up cluster
doParallel::registerDoParallel(number_cores)

# run simulation
start <- Sys.time() # for microbenchmarking
temp_result <- foreach (i = seq_len(number_cores),.packages="lme4") %dopar% { # %dopar% evaluates in parallel
  manyimulations_gamma(ni = ni, nj = nj, RI_sd = RI_sd, gamma02 = gamma02, gamma20 = gamma20, niter = niter)
  #main function 
}
Sys.time()-start

# stop cluster
doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()

res <- do.call(rbind, temp_result)
save(res, file = "sim_res_gamma_test.rda")
```

But when trying to run the more complex simulation I get the following Error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': subscript out of bounds"

Unfortunately, I'm not able to recreate the error. And my simulation has neither the argument 'x' nor the function 't' in it...
Any idea what that error message refers to?

Thanks!

Edit:
Here would be the whole code of the simulation:
I am creating multilevel-data while varying the effect of some of the predictor variable in my model.

```
# parallalization -------------------------------------------------------------------------

number_cores <- 4


# lmer Model --------------------------------------------------------------

lmer_function <- function(dgp_grid,model){
  
  
  if (model == 1) { #lmer model with two predictors
    
    model <- lmer(yij_2_p ~ x1ij + z1j + (1|nj), data = dgp_grid)<
    #lmer.  linear models for mixed effects
    # summary(model)
    
    coefs_x1ij <- t(coefficients(summary(model))["x1ij", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")])
    cc <- coefficients(summary(model))
    if (!"z1j" %in% rownames(cc)) {
      coefs_z1j <- data.frame(
        z1j = NA,
        Estimate = NA,
        Std.Error = NA,
        Pvalue = NA
      )
    } else {
      coefs_z1j <-
        t(coefficients(summary(model))["z1j", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")])
    }
    #save coef of lmer model
    
    
    res_lmer <- cbind(data.frame(coefs_x1ij),
                      data.frame(coefs_z1j)
    )
    
    colnames(res_lmer)[1] ="estimate_x1ij_lmer_model"
    colnames(res_lmer)[2] ="std.err_x1ij_lmer_model"
    colnames(res_lmer)[3] ="p_x1ij_lmer_model"
    colnames(res_lmer)[4] ="estimate_z1j_lmer_model"
    colnames(res_lmer)[5] ="std.err_z1j_lmer_model"
    colnames(res_lmer)[6] ="p_z1j_lmer_model"
    
    return(res_lmer) 
    
  } else if (model == 2) { 
 
    model <- lmer(yij_4_p ~ x1ij + z1j + x2ij + z2j + (1|nj), data = dgp_grid)  
    #lmer.  linear models for mixed effects with effects for two variables
    summary(model)
    
    coefs_x1ij <- t(coefficients(summary(model))["x1ij", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")])
    coefs_x2ij <- t(coefficients(summary(model))["x2ij", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")])
    
    cc <- coefficients(summary(model))
    
    if (!"z1j" %in% rownames(cc)) {
      coefs_z1j <- data.frame(
        z1j = NA,
        Estimate = NA,
        Std.Error = NA,
        Pvalue = NA
      )
    } else {
      coefs_z1j <-
        t(coefficients(summary(model))["z1j", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")])
    }
    
    if (!"z2j" %in% rownames(cc)) {
      coefs_z2j <- data.frame(
        z2j = NA,
        Estimate = NA,
        Std.Error = NA,
        Pvalue = NA
      )
    } else {
      coefs_z2j <-
        t(coefficients(summary(model))["z2j", c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "Pr(>|t|)")])
    }
    #save coef of lmer model (effects of two predictors)
    
    res_lmer <- cbind(
      data.frame(coefs_x1ij),
      data.frame(coefs_z1j),
      data.frame(coefs_x2ij),
      data.frame(coefs_z2j)
    )
    
    
    colnames(res_lmer)[1] ="estimate_x1ij_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[2] ="std.err_x1ij_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[3] ="p_x1ij_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[4] ="estimate_z1j_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[5] ="std.err_z1j_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[6] ="p_z1j_lmer_model_4p"
    
    colnames(res_lmer)[7] ="estimate_x2ij_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[8] ="std.err_x2ij_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[9] ="p_x2ij_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[10] ="estimate_z2j_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[11] ="std.err_z2j_lmer_model_4p"
    colnames(res_lmer)[12] ="p_z2j_lmer_model_4p"
    
    return(res_lmer) 
    
    
  } else {
    return(print("model not specified"))
  }



}

#x <- lmer_function(dgp_grid, model =2)


# data generating-------------------------------------------------------------------------
dgp_pilot_study_gamma <- function(ni,nj, RI_sd, sigma2 = 1,
                gamma00 = 0, gamma01 = 0, gamma10 = 0, gamma02 = 0, gamma20 = 0){
  
  dgp_grid <- expand.grid(
    ni = 1:ni,
    nj = 1:nj,
    gamma02 = gamma02,
    gamma20 = gamma20,
    x1ij = NA,
    x2ij = NA,
    z1j = NA,
    z2j = NA,
    yij_2_p = NA, # with two predictor variables
    yij_4_p = NA, # with four predictor variables
    Rij = sigma2,
    U0j = RI_sd
  )
  
  dgp_grid$z1j <- rep(rbinom(nj,1,0.5), each = length(1:ni))
  #create a random factorial level 2 predictor z1j, same value for the whole cluster
  
  dgp_grid$z2j <- rep(rbinom(nj,1,0.5), each = length(1:ni))
  #create a random factorial level 2 predictor z2j, same value for the whole cluster
  
  dgp_grid$U0j <- rep(rnorm(nj, mean = 0, sd = RI_sd), each = ni)
  #create level 2 residual 
  
  dgp_grid$Rij <- rnorm(ni*nj, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(sigma2))
  # create level 1 residual with sigma2 = 1
  
  dgp_grid$x1ij <- rbinom(ni*nj,1,0.5)
  # create level 1 x1ij explanatory/predictor variable (draw from standard normal)
  
  dgp_grid$x2ij <- rbinom(ni*nj,1,0.5)
  # create level 1 x2ij explanatory/predictor variable (draw from standard normal)
  
  
  dgp_grid$yij_2_p <-
    gamma00 + gamma10 * dgp_grid$x1ij + gamma01 * dgp_grid$z1j +
    dgp_grid$U0j + dgp_grid$Rij
  #creating yij with only two predictor without any effect
  
  dgp_grid$yij_4_p <-
    gamma00 + gamma10 * dgp_grid$x1ij + dgp_grid$gamma20 * dgp_grid$x2ij + gamma01 * dgp_grid$z1j + dgp_grid$gamma02 * dgp_grid$z2j +
    dgp_grid$U0j + dgp_grid$Rij
  #creating yij with four predictors x2ij and z2j having an effect
  
  
  return(dgp_grid)
}

#test_dgp<-dgp(ni = 30, nj = 30, RI_sd = 2)

# one_simulation -------------------------------------------------------------------------

one_simulation_gamma <- function(ni,nj,gamma02,gamma20,RI_sd) {
  
  dgp_grid <-dgp_pilot_study_gamma(ni,nj,RI_sd,gamma02,gamma20)
  #creating the data
  
  res_lmer_function_model_2 <- lmer_function(dgp_grid, model = 2)
  #lmer.  linear models for mixed effects
  #yij_4_p ~ x1ij + z1j + x2ij + z2j + (1|nj)
  
  
  return(res_lmer_function_model_2)
}


# many simulations gamma ---------------------------------------------------

design_grid <- expand.grid(ni = ni,
                           nj = nj, 
                           RI_sd= RI_sd,
                           gamma02 = gamma02,
                           gamma20 = gamma20,
                           replication = 1:niter
)

design_grid$ID <- seq.int(nrow(design_grid))

manyimulations_gamma <- function(design_grid){
    
  sim_results_pilot_study_gamma <- matrix(nrow = nrow(design_grid), ncol = 12)
  
  colnames(sim_results_pilot_study_gamma) = c(
    "estimate_x1ij_lmer_model_4p",
    "std.err_x1ij_lmer_model_4p",
    "p_x1ij_lmer_model_4p",       
    "estimate_z1j_lmer_model_4p",
    "std.err_z1j_lmer_model_4p",
    "p_z1j_lmer_model_4p",        
    "estimate_x2ij_lmer_model_4p",
    "std.err_x2ij_lmer_model_4p",
    "p_x2ij_lmer_model_4p",       
    "estimate_z2j_lmer_model_4p",
    "std.err_z2j_lmer_model_4p",
    "p_z2j_lmer_model_4p"
  )
  
  sim_results_pilot_study_gamma <- as.data.frame(sim_results_pilot_study_gamma)
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(design_grid)){
    res<- one_simulation_gamma(ni = design_grid$ni[i],
                                nj = design_grid$nj[i],
                                gamma02 = design_grid$gamma02[i],
                                gamma20 = design_grid$gamma20[i],
                                RI_sd = design_grid$RI_sd[i])
    
    
    sim_results_pilot_study_gamma[i,] <- res
    
    
  }
  
  sim_results_pilot_study_gamma<- cbind(design_grid,sim_results_pilot_study_gamma)
  
  return(sim_results_pilot_study_gamma)
  
}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

niter <- 100
#numbers of iterations

ni <- 30
#numbers of student per class
#ni <- seq(10,30,10)

nj <- 30
#numbers of clusters/classes

ICC <- seq(.1,.9,.1) 
#starting with 0, then going up .1 stepwise till .9, thus generating 10 values

# what is the random intercept standard deviation given icc? 
RI_sd <- sqrt(1 / (1-ICC) - 1) 
# RI_sd

sigma2 = 1
#level 1 residual with sigma2 = 1


gamma00 <- 0
#is the mean value of the L1 dependent variable, controlling for the L2 predijtor Wj

gamma01 <- 0
#is the effect (slope) of the L2 predictor
#effect of z1j

gamma02 <- seq(0.5,1,0.5)
#gamma02 <- 0.5
#is the effect (slope) of the L2 predictor
#effect of z2j

gamma10 <- 0
#is the mean value of Level1 slope, controlling for the L2 predictor Wj
#effect of x1ij

gamma20 <- seq(0.5,1,0.5)
#gamma20 <- 0.5
#is the mean value of Level1 slope, controlling for the L2 predictor Wj
#effect of x2ij
```